# Magento2 image name doesn't save in Custom db

Tags: magento2, image-upload

Here I am trying to save the image name which will be stored in the `URl_TYPE_Media` `banner/Banner/image` , but image name is not saving in DB. below code is what i have done so far. I am new to magento2

> Form.php

```
<?php

namespace Zyxware\Banner\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit;

/**
 * Adminhtml Add New Row Form.
 */
class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
     * @param \Zyxware\Banner\Model\Status $options,
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('banner_data');
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => [
                            'id' => 'edit_form',
                            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                            'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                            'method' => 'post'
                        ]
            ]
        );

        if ($model->getbannerId()) {
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'base_fieldset',
                ['legend' => __('Edit banner'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
            );
            $fieldset->addField('banner_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'banner_id']);
        } else {
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'base_fieldset',
                ['legend' => __('Add banner'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
            );
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
            'name',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'name',
                'label' => __('Name'),
                'id' => 'name',
                'title' => __('Name'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );

        $wysiwygConfig = $this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig(['tab_id' => $this->getTabId()]);

        $fieldset->addField(
            'content',
            'editor',
            [
                'name' => 'content',
                'label' => __('Content'),
                'style' => 'height:36em;',
                'required' => true,
                'config' => $wysiwygConfig
            ]
        );


        $fieldset->addField(
            'image',
            'image',
            array(
                'name' => 'image',
                'label' => __('Image'),
                'title' => __('Image'),
                'required' => true
            )
        );
        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

> Save.php

```
<?php
namespace Zyxware\Banner\Controller\Adminhtml\Banner;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Zyxware\Banner\Model\BannerFactory
     */
    var $gridFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Zyxware\Banner\Model\BannerFactory $gridFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Zyxware\Banner\Model\BannerFactory $gridFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->gridFactory = $gridFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$data) {
            $this->_redirect('banner/banner/addrow');
            return;
        }
        try {
            $rowData = $this->gridFactory->create();
            $rowData->setData($data);
            if (isset($data['id'])) {
                $rowData->setEntityId($data['id']);
            }
            $rowData->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Banner has been successfully saved.'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
        $this->_redirect('banner/banner/index');
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Zyxware_Banner::save');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for my question. The solution is posted below in case if anyone need any  help feel free to comment below . Create a function for image in Save.php and call it inside the execute function

```
 private function _processbanner_image($data, $model){

        try{


            $media_dir_obj = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                                                    ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);                                                                        
            $media_dir = $media_dir_obj->getAbsolutePath();


            if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])){

                $Uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
                                               'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
                                                ['fileId' => 'image']);

                $Uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
                $Uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);

                $banner_dir = $media_dir.'/zyxware/banner/banner/image';                                
                $result = $Uploader->save($banner_dir);

                unset($result['tmp_name']);
                unset($result['path']);

                $data['image'] = $Uploader->getUploadedFileName();

            }else{

                if(isset($data['image']['delete'])){

                    $data['image'] = '';

                }else{

                    if($model->getId()) {

                        if($model->getImage() != ''){                                        
                            $data['image'] = $model->getImage();
                        }

                    }else{
                        $data['image'] = '';
                    }
                }
            }

            if(isset($data['image']))
                return $data['image'];    


        } catch (\Exception $e) {

                $this->messageManager->addError(
                        __($e->getMessage())
                );                                
        }
```